# How to hide the thing on the right-hand side for better screen ratio?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is this thing on the right-hand side and how to get rid of this thing? I am struggling with screen utilization as this thing is eating up space.

[image: VS Code screenshot with the thing on the right hand side]

Comment: Search for `minimap` in the settings - you can disable that from appearing.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer.